# New Power BI Embedded pricing model - page render

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I am not sure I understand totally the term *page render* in new Power BI Embedded pricing model.

[image]

We need to measure how often our clients load Power BI in order to charge them properly. But we still got the confusion how page render is counted under the hood.

From the definition:

> A page render is counted any time Power BI visuals are loaded on a page. A page refresh counts as a page render, as does any other page interactivity, like slice and dice, filtering, etc. Typically, multiple queries running on the backend cores translate to a page render.

How we can understand Page Render in both cases Import and Direct Query mode for Report Embedding.

**Scenario 1 with import mode:**

Assume one page in our application *embeds an report with import mode*. This report has 2 tabs inside and each tab has 5 visual. So, this report has 10 visuals in total.

How many page render if user visits this page: 1 render (based on the whole report), or 2 (based on 2 tabs), or 10 (based on 10 visuals).

If user switches between two tabs in the report, is there any page render is count?

Now assume there is datetime slicer in the tab 1, if user use this slicer to do filtering. One render is counted on this case?

**Scenario 2 with direct query:**

The same with the scenario 1 with direct query report.

Answer (score 2):

Im Aviv the PM for Power BI Embedded. Trying to add clarity and answer the above. A page render could be translated to queries running against the analytical data model. Every time a page is loading, each visual is running at least 1 query against the data model to get the aggregated data back and render the visual based on that data. Each query could be with a different level of complexity. Because it is impossible to make concrete statements on a page render due to the number of visuals on a page plus the complexity of the query ran to render these, we tried providing generic guidance about sizing. A page render == 10 queries ran against the data model. Each page load is a page render, unless it is already cached on the client side. Each time you apply a new filter on a visual/page there is a recalc and therefore a page render.
Hope this helps
Aviv